# Proving that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in $L^q$ (with Hölder)

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to prove that convergence of a function $f \in L^p$ implies that $f$ converges in $L^q$, for $1\le q\le p < \infty$, where $\mu(X) < \infty$.

I have already been able to prove this fact, by splitting the integral in two parts, where $|f| \geq 1$ and $|f| \le 1$.

However, apparently you can prove this with Jensen's inequality or Hölder's inequality.

If this is actually provable with the Hölder inequality, how could this be done?
What I have tried is using the inequality twice, once for $p$ and once for $q$, with $\frac {p}{p-1}$ or $\frac{q}{q-1}$ to fulfill the requirements. Then I would use $g := 1$ and I end up with:

$$||f||_p \mu(X)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}-||f||_q\mu(X)^{\frac{q-1}{q}} \ge 0$$

but this does not generally prove the fact,  since $\frac{p-1}{p}$ is greater than $\frac{q-1}{q}$.

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply Hölder's inequality to $|f_n-f|^q \times 1$ and the exponents ${p \over q}$ and ${p \over p - q}$ to get
$$\int_X|f_n - f|^q\,dx \leq \mu(X)^{p - q \over q}\left(\int_X|f_n - f|^p\,dx\right)^{q \over p}$$
and thus the result follows since $\mu(X)<+\infty$ and so the right-hand side tends to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Using Jensen's Inequality
$$
        (E|X|^q)^{\frac{p}{q}} \leq E|X|^{\frac{q p}{q}} = E|X|^p.
$$
Now, just take the $p$-th root
$$
        ((E|X|^q)^{\frac{p}{q}})^{1/p} = (E|X|^q)^{1/q} \leq (E|X|^p)^{1/p}.
$$

To clarify, note that $E |X|^p \equiv E\left[|X|^p\right]$, while
$\left(E |X|\right)^p \equiv \left(E\left[|X|\right]\right)^p$.